# How do I pass paramters to function dynamically and execute stored procedure dynamically

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, function, stored-procedures

I have two questions to ask at this point

1. How do I pass parameters to a function where the number of parameters is unknown until the function is invoked?(SQL Server 2008)
2. How do I execute a stored procedure dynamically inside a function and return table?

To make the question more clear I am adding a small piece of code for calling method in `C#` for  where the number of parameters is unknown until the function is invoked. Please excuse.

```
public void DemoFunction(string name,params string[] list)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
    {
        // Do whatever we want
    }        
}
```

In C# we can invoke the above method like

```
DemoFunction("MyName","A","B",....etc etc)
```

**QUESTION 1**

Can I define parameters to be dynamic in the Sql Server function as like the `C#` code I have given above (`params string[] list`)?

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].ExecStoredProc ( @ProcName varchar(40),@Param1 INT,@Param2 VARCHAR(50))
(
    ....
    ....
    ....
)
```

**QUESTION 2**

- The name of `stored procedure` to execute will be passed to this `function`.
- The parameters for executing `stored procedure` will be passed to this `function` but should be dynamic(as in Question 1)
- I need to execute `stored procedure` that is passing as parameter to this function dynamically inside the `function` and return the result as a table.
- How do I declare a table for returning the result where the number of columns are unknown until the procedure is executed?

Here is the code I have tried so far

```
 -- Here the parameters should be dynamic as like params string[] list
    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].ExecStoredProc (@ProcName varchar(40),@Param1 INT,@Param2 VARCHAR(50))    
    RETURNS @ReturnTable TABLE
       (
           COLUMN1 INT
          ,COLUMN2 DATETIME
          ,COLUMN3 VARCHAR(50)      
       )
    AS
    BEGIN
       -- Is it possible like SELECT * INTO @ReturnTable FROM(Exec @ProcName)?
       INSERT INTO @ReturnTable  

       -- This should be dynamic including the number of parameters      
       Exec @ProcName 'Params'

       RETURN
    END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short....

Question 1
No, you can not declare dynamic parameters in SQL like you can in C#

Question 2
EXEC is not allowed within User Defined Functions. The only way to execute a procedure within a function is to call into CLR.

The table returned by a user defined table valued function is static, and declared in the return statement. You can't return dynamic columns.

Read more about SQL User defined functions [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214363(v=SQL.80).aspx)

Hope that helps